# Причастный оборот (ЕГЭ)

Tags: грамотная-речь, причастный-оборот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка:

**Лодка, проплывающая мимо меня, привлекла моё внимание.**

Comment: ошибка скорее всего в данном тесте. Поскольку есть один такой тест, но там написано так, как я написал в ответе.   ***Лодка привлекла моё внимание, проплывающая мимо меня***.

Comment: @Серж всё-таки надо давать ссылку, а не требовать веры в ваши слова. Во-первых, другое (то, что я нашел) не тест, и к ЕГЭ отношения не имеет, А-во-вторых, чему верить и почему?

Comment: Какую ссылку? Я имел в виду ту ссылку на тест, который предоставил автор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибки нет, во всяком слычае уровня ЕГЭ.

Сразу. Разговоры про согласование времен следует оставить досужим академикам.

> согласование времен
>   Зависимость временных форм придаточного предложения от форм времени
>   главного предложения в некоторых языках *(в русском языке это
>   грамматическое явление отсутствует)*.

(курсив мой)

Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. Изд. 2-е. — М.: Просвещение. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.. 1976. 
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1528/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Посему. Оба варианта совершенно правильны:

**1. Лодка, проплывающая мимо меня, привлекла моё внимание.
2. Лодка, проплывшая мимо меня, привлекла моё внимание.**

Но у них несколько разный смысл. Ну или может быть разным.
В русском языке время - относительно, причастие настоящего времени означает, что лодка проплывает в настоящий момент по отношению ко времени повествования, а "проплывавшая" не дает оснований считать так наверняка. "Привлекла" же говорит о том, что само повествование идет по отношению к прошедшему времени. ***Если фраза не отражает последовательности действий, то это ошибка логическая, но не грамматическая.***

Поэтому вариант 1. даже более естественен и логичен.

(-------------------------------)

**Теперь самое главное.**
Источник именно этого варианта фразы можно узнать?
В сети обнаружен только один случай чего-то подобного.

5) Лодка привлекла моё внимание, проплывающая мимо меня.
https://ds04.infourok.ru/uploads/doc/0a69/000365c8-670b8ba9.docx

Тут ошибка очевидна.

Если же я ошибаюсь, и формулировка примера именно такая, то не исключаю, что техническая ошибка все равно имеет место, только она произошла на этапе подготовки материала для вашего источника. Такое тоже бывает. 
Корректор/редактор механически исправил фразу, упустив из виду, что ошибка тут нарочитая, для упражнения.

Comment: https://ege.yandex.ru/ege/exam/89/task/38130/question/52129  источник

Comment: @qwertyy. Ясно, спасибо. Полагаю, что это недоразумение. Вы правильно нашли номер подразумеваемого ответа, потому, что все остальное очевидно не подходит. Но уровень заданий во всем тесте примерно одинаковый, вряд ли там умышленно затесалось что-то настолько нетривиальное. Видимо все-таки это ошибка при подготовке.

Comment: @qwertyy. и да. Само появление "теста к ЕГЭ", в котором предлагают писать ответы без знаков препинания и даже без пробелов в словах вызывает вполне законные вопросы. Это ж не просто халтура, это вредительство какое-то. Найдите что-нибудь более адекватное.

Comment: Да не за что. Про "согласование времен" в русском. Это тему постоянно мусолят стилисты (филологические), но  стилистика - не моё хобби (особенно - принудительная) и вообще вещь довольно субъективная. В русском есть совершенно четкий грамматическо-семантический запрет на неестественный порядок следования сказуемых разных виловременных форм: "Мальчик смотрит на меня с удивлением и сделал шаг навстречу" (пример из этого же теста). Он очевидно неправильный, иной порядок сказуемых был бы приемлем ("[уже] сделал шаг и [теперь] смотрит"). Но это никак не касается причастных оборотов и придаточных.

Comment: Тут все просто. Однако научные споры (далеко выходящие за рамки школьной программы) о самом понятии согласования времен в русском ведутся (например, в части теории перевода). Это связано с бедностью видовременной системы русского глагола. Но не надо переносить это на ЕГЭ, это вопрос на данный момент сугубо академический. Этим и была вызвана моя реплика о "досужих академиках".

Answer (score -1):

В тесте ЭГЭ надо найти грамматические ошибки. В данном случае речь идет о  нарушении в построении предложения с причастным оборотом:

> Лодка привлекла моё внимание, проплывающая мимо меня.

Здесь причастный оборот отдален от определяемого слова. Так что в вашем примере ошибки нет.

Comment: О каком тесте ЕГЭ идет речь? Он в сети есть?

Comment: В сети он есть. Косноязычия нет. Если вам неизвестно, что такое нарушение в построении с причастным оборотом, это не говорит о косноязычии.

Comment: @Morkovkin Если вы заметили у кого-либо опечатку или ошибку, то вы имеете право исправить этот текст. Давайте будем уважительно относиться ко всем участникам сообщества.